# WPF Create global WinSCP session

Tags: c#, wpf, global-variables, winscp, winscp-net

I am trying to create a global WinSCP session. I am needing to use the session in two different places in my application to `GetFiles` and `PutFiles`. My issue is it takes so long to create the session its really slowing down the application. I tried what I have below to create a global session but I get a session is disposed exception when I run it. Is it possible to open a session at one spot and use it everywhere in the application.

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Session GlobalSession;

    private static Session OpenSession()
    {
        SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
        {
            Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
        
            HostName = @"server",
            UserName = "name",
            PortNumber = 22,
            SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 RSAKEY",
        };

        using (Session session = new Session())
        {
            // Connect
            session.Open(sessionOptions);
            return session;
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        Session LocalSession = OpenSession();
        GlobalSession = LocalSession;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string path = "";
        try
        {
            // Upload files
            TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
            transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;

            TransferOperationResult transferResult;

            RemoteDirectoryInfo subDirs = GlobalSession.ListDirectory(path);

            foreach(var sub in subDirs.Files)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(sub.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex);
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Upload files
            TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
            transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;

            TransferOperationResult transferResult =
                GlobalSession.GetFiles(
                    @"d:\toupload\*", "/home/user/File", false, transferOptions);

            // Throw on any error
            transferResult.Check();

            // Print results
            foreach (TransferEventArgs transfer in transferResult.Transfers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Upload of {0} succeeded", transfer.FileName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the [`using` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/using) that disposes the session, by implicitly calling the [`Session.Dispose` method](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_dispose). That's its purpose. But you do not want it in your case. Remove it.

```
private static Session OpenSession()
{
    SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
    {
        Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,

        HostName = @"server",
        UserName = "name",
        PortNumber = 22,
        SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 RSAKEY",
    };

    // Connect
    session.Open(sessionOptions);
    return session;
}
```

And make sure you dispose the `Session` instance, by explicitly calling the `Session.Dispose` method, once it is not needed.

You can, for example, override the [`OnClosed` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.onclosed) (or handle the [`Closed` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.closed)):

```
protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
{
    GlobalSession.Dispose();
    base.OnClosed(e);
}
```

---

*Though you should really do any session opening/file transferring on a background thread. Not on the GUI thread. But that's a different topic.*

Comment: Haha thanks and yes all the transfers are on a background i just put my code in here so you did not have to see all 1000 lines :)

Answer (score 2):

Your `using` statement is disposing the session as soon as it goes out of scope:

```
 using (Session session = new Session())
 {
    // Connect
    session.Open(sessionOptions);
    return session;
 } //<-------------------- SESSION DISPOSED HERE!!
```

Remove the `using` and call `Dispose()` manually if necessary when all your objects have finished with the session